# Сохранить значение $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] переменной в файле до его включения в другой файл

Tags: php

Есть файл `/includes/func.php` и он подключается во многих файлах через `require()`.
В нем `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, которая имеет значение `/includes/func.php`,
но при включении файла `/includes/func.php`, к примеру, в `/index.php` переменная будет принимать значение уже исполняемого файла, поэтому в БД запишется путь исполняемого файла вместо, требуемого, подключаемого.

Можно как-то отловить содержимое чтобы в разных исполняемых файлах записать именно путь включаемого файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения пути к файлу из самого файла существует магическая константа `__FILE__`. Ее значение зависит только от файла, в котором она используется и не зависит от файла, в котором вызывается `require` (`include`).

Подробнее: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Дмитрий, благодарю, это оно. А чем лучше отсечь абсолютный путь от нее, чтобы получился относительно корня документов? То есть превратить `/home/user/site/htdocs/includes/func.php` => `/includes/func.php`

Comment: Если путь `/home/user/site/htdocs` заранее известен, то можно и `str_replace`